Count all countries that are not on the list
Every month I have to compile a count of all countries received that month. Specific countries are counted individually for occurences, and the rest goes into a count for "other".
For example I might receive a list of countries as such:
"my, my, ch, de, de, fr, fi, ch, fr, fr, gb, fr, fr, sg, sg, sg, my, gr, es, it, nl, gb, at, us, at, ie, pt, my, gr, ru, ru"
where cn, my, de, sg, are counted in their own individual rows,
and anything that isn't cn, my, de, or sg are counted as other.
I have set up countif for the individual countries counted, however how do I get a count of the countries that are not the ones already counted?
I have tried countif <> to exclude cn, my, de, sg however I keep getting an error message. I also tried doing a COUNTA for the whole list, and then tried to deduct the countries that are NOT other, but would still get an error message. I'm not sure how to set up the formula.

You can use COUNTIFS with multiple criteria to find countries that are NOT other: https://exceljet.net/formulas/countifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic.  But I still want to state the obvious: if you already have the count of cn, my, de, and sg in individual rows, why can't you just sum up the count of the those rows, and deduct this sum from COUNTA?

What are the error messages you're getting?

To double-check: you are after the number of times countries appear, rather than the number of individual countries?  (In the former case, you would get cn: 0; my: 4; de: 2; sg: 3; Other: 22, but in the latter case you would get cn: 0; my: 1; de: 1; sg: 1; Other: 13)

With COUNT and SUM functions
cell D2: =COUNTIF(A$1:A$31,C2) and drag down for all the individual types
cell D6: =ROWS(A1:A31)-SUM(D2:D5)


You could try using the following formula:


=LET(
     _Req, {"cn";"my";"de";"sg"},
     _List, A1:A31,
     _ReqCounts, COUNTIFS(_List,_Req),
     VSTACK(HSTACK(_Req,_ReqCounts),
            HSTACK("Others",COUNTA(_List)-SUM(_ReqCounts))))


Or, If applicable can use GROUPBY():
=LET(
     _Req, {"cn";"my";"de";"sg"},
     _List, A1:A31,
     _New, IF(ISNA(XMATCH(_List,_Req)),"Others",_List),
     GROUPBY(_New,_New,ROWS,,0,2))



This is using a sledge hammer to crack a tiny nut, just the total and subtract the ones known. However, as a method for very large datasets it may be relevant.

@SolarMike sir while doing speed testing, COUNTIFS() is quicker than FREQUENCY(). also since I'm not aware whether Op needs a single cell formula or copy down ones. Yes Black Cats is simpler.

Using FREQUENCY, enter the following in the first cell (as D2 in the screenshot):
=LET(
    long_list, A2:INDEX(A:A, COUNTA(A:A)),
    short_list, DROP(C2:INDEX(C:C, COUNTA(C:C)), -1),
    bins, SEQUENCE(ROWS(short_list)),
    other, MAX(bins) + 1,
    FREQUENCY(IFNA(XMATCH(long_list, short_list), other), bins)
)


